# How to get string representation for the member function?

Tags: c++, casting, function-pointers

As a part of hashing, I need to convert a function pointer to a string representation. With global/static functions it's trivial:

```
string s1{ to_string(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&global)) };
```

And from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast):

> 2) Any pointer can be converted to any integral type large enough to
>   hold the value of the pointer (e.g. to `std::uintptr_t`)

But I have a problems with member functions:

```
cout << &MyStruct::member;
```

outputs `1` though in debugger I can see the address.

```
string s{ to_string(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&MyStruct::member)) };
```

Gives a compile-time error `cannot convert`. So it seems that not any pointer can be converted.

What else can I do to get a string representation?

Comment: `1` might well be the correct value. Member function pointers are relative, after all. Which also means that you might run into a lot of collisions if you don't add additional information like the hash of the typeid of the type itself. And when you say that *not any pointer can be converted*, bear in mind that member function pointers *are not* pointers; they are precisely *member function pointers*.

Comment: "So it seems that not any pointer can be converted. ..." A pointer is not the same thing as a pointer to member, pointers can be converted to an integral type, pointers to member can't.

Comment: There is no `operator <<` for pointer-to-member. `&MyStruct::member` is a non-null pointer-to-member. Any pointer can be implicitly converted to `bool`. Non-null pointers convert to `true`, which print as `1` by default.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz _"Member function pointers are relative, after all."_ Not in most implementations. That would break all kinds of sane code if you change things in a class definition. Non-virtual member function pointers are typically a function pointer + additional info for adjusting the `this` pointer. As others have pointed out, `1` is the result of converting a non-null pointer-to-member to `bool`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> cout << &MyStruct::member;
> ```
>
> outputs `1` though in debugger I can see the address.

There is no overload for `ostream::operator<<(decltype(&MyStruct::member))`. However, the member function pointer is implicitly convertible to `bool` and for that, there exists an overload and that is the best match for overload resolution. The converted value is `true` if the pointer is not null. `true` is output as `1`.

---

> ```
> string s{ to_string(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&MyStruct::member)) };
> ```
>
> Gives a compile-time error cannot convert. So it seems that not any pointer can be converted.

Perhaps confusingly, in standardese *pointer* is not an umbrella term for object pointers, pointers-to-members, pointers-to-functions and pointers-to-member-functions. Pointers mean just data pointers specifically.

So, the quoted rule does not apply to pointers-to-member-functions. It only applies to (object) pointers.

---

> What else can I do to get a string representation?

You can use a buffer of `unsigned char`, big enough to represent the pointer, and use `std::memcpy`. Then print it in the format of your own choice. I recommend hexadecimal.

As Martin Bonner points out, the pointer-to-member may contain padding in which case two values that point to the same member may actually have a different value in the buffer. Therefore the printed value is not of much use because two values are not comparable without knowing which bits (if any) are padding - which is implementation defined.

---

> Unfortunately I need a robust solution so because of this padding I can't use.

No *portable* robust solution exists.

As Jonathan Wakely points out, there is no padding in the Itanium ABI, so if your compiler uses that, then the suggested memcpy method would work.

Comment: There is a risk that some of the data of a *pointer-to-member* is ignored padding space.  In that case, different variables containing a pointer to the same member might have different padding values - and printing this out in hex would (incorrectly) yield a different hash.  I'm not sure this is a problem which can be solved (in general) without compiler support.  (In practise of course, your suggestion will probably work.)

Comment: @MartinBonner good point. I hadn't considered what nikitablack might be using the string representation for.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I need a robust solution so because of this padding I can't use. Moreover, I don't know how to copy it. `memcpy` accepts `void*` as source but *pointer-to-member* can't be converted to it.

Comment: @nikitablack if you want to copy the bits of a member pointer then you want the address of a variable that holds its value, not the address of the member function itself. So `auto mp = &Foo::bar; void* vp = &mp;`, not `void* vp = &Foo::bar;`

Comment: For implementations that use the common Itanium C++ ABI there is no padding, see https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#member-pointers for the implementation details.